# Original index position after filtering an array

Tags: javascript

I have an array that is filtered based on what the user types into a search box..

```
var x = ["Apple","Pear","Pineapple"];

var value = e.target.value;

var regex = new RegExp(`^${value}`, 'i');

var filtered = x.sort().filter(v => regex.test(v));
```

If I were to type "P" into the search box the console would print

```
["Pear","Pineapple"]
```

What I need however is another array of the **original** index position of Pear and Pineapple that would print the following

```
[1,2]
```

How would I go about achieving this?

Comment: where is the regex?

Comment: Forgot to add it, it's in there now

Comment: Maybe you can use `var indices = filtered.map(f => x.indexOf(f));`? Since you keep a copy of the original unmodified array in `x`.

Comment: and where is 'value'?

Comment: Filter `keys` instead of `values`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that in a single shot using `reduce` ([read more about reduce here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)).
There is no need to filter, you can just generate another array, keep track of the index of the currently looped item (assuming you want the **sorted** index).

If you don't want the sorted index, just **remove .sort**. Not sure why it's there in the first place.
This solution requires a single iteration, which should be optimal (as long as you remove the unneeded sort).

```js
var x = ["Apple","Pear","Pineapple"];
var value = 'P';
var regex = new RegExp(`^${value}`, 'i');

var filtered = x.sort().reduce((acc, next, i) => { // acc is the current accumulator (initially an empty array), next is looped item, i is item's index (what you want in the result).
  return regex.test(next) && acc.push(i), acc // <-- if the regex test is successfull, `i` is pushed to the accumulator. In both cases (so, even if the regex fails) the accumulator is returned for the next iteration.
}, []); // <-- [] is the initial value of `acc`, which is a new empty array.
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of filtering the array, `filter` the [`keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys) of the array instead:

```js
var x = ["Apple","Pear","Pineapple"],
    value ="P",
    regex = new RegExp(`^${value}`, 'i'),
    filtered = [...x.keys()].filter(i => regex.test(x[i]));

console.log(filtered)
```

`keys()` method returns a *Array Iterator*. So, you need to use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) or [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to convert it to an array

Answer (score 3):

You can get your indexes with `indexOf()` from the original array like so:

```js
const x = ["Apple","Pear","Pineapple"];

var regex = new RegExp(`^P`, 'i');

const filtered = x.sort().filter(v => regex.test(v));
const filteredIndexes = filtered.map(v => x.indexOf(v));

console.log(filtered);
console.log(filteredIndexes);
```

You could also use reduce to do it all in one iteration like the so:

```js
const x = ["Apple","Pear","Pineapple"];

var regex = new RegExp(`^P`, 'i');

const [filtered, filteredIndexes] = x.sort().reduce((acc, val, i) => {
  // If the regex fits, add to the arrays
  if(regex.test(val)) {
    // Adding to the array via array spread operator
    acc = [[...acc[0], val],[...acc[1], i]];
  }
  return acc;
}, [[],[]]); // Initial value of accumulator

console.log(filtered);
console.log(filteredIndexes);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could get first the value/index pairs, filter and get either the values or indices.

Intead of a [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/), you could use [`String#startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith), which has no problems of characters with special meanings.

```js
var array = ["Apple", "Pear", "Pineapple"],
    value = 'P',
    filtered = array
        .sort()
        .map((v, i) => [v, i])
        .filter(([v]) => v.startsWith(value)),
    values = filtered.map(([v]) => v),
    indices = filtered.map(([, i]) => i);

console.log(values);
console.log(indices);
```